# Combining SELECT with SELECT DISTINCT in DBBrowser SQLite

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite, multiple-select-query

I've got a query to select distinct results with two tables which returns email addresses that don't occur in `table2`, but I'm having trouble also selecting data from the `Table 2.First` in this query for all rows with distinct emails. Is it possible to combine select statements in SQLite/DBbrowser in this way? My current query with the syntax I've tried is below

TABLE1:

| table1email | Firstlast |
| --- | --- |
| fjj4@gmil.com | Jim Robinson |
| oei@yahoo.com | Clark Stevenson |

TABLE2:

| table2email | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fjj4@gmil.com | Jim | Robinson |
| jj6@hotmail.com | Susan | Peters |
| oei@yahoo.com | Clark | Stevenson |

QUERY:

```
SELECT table1email
FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT table2email
SELECT First
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't seems to be very clear. Whatever I can understand from the question this seems to be the solution you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT table1email FROM table1 
WHERE table1email NOT IN (
    SELECT table2email FROM table2
);
```

This will work even if table2 have duplicate entries. But this will result duplicate entries from table1.
If that is also needs to be eliminated, DISTINCT keyword can be used.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT table1email FROM table1 
WHERE table1email NOT IN (
    SELECT table2email FROM table2
);
```